Not able to Login in react native app using oauth Connected app
I am trying to build a Salesforce react native mobile app. I am doing Oauth with Salesforce. I am using react-native-app-auth package and Salesforce connected app for this. Below are details for my connected app. 
My react native code is
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, Alert, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { authorize, refresh, revoke } from 'react-native-app-auth';

const OAuthComponent = () => {
  // State to hold OAuth token data
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOpenURL = (url) => {
      // Handle the incoming URL and extract parameters
      const { path, queryParams } = Linking.parse(url);
      if (path === 'oauth/callback') {
        // Handle successful authentication here
        console.log('Redirected with URL:', url);
      }
    };

    // Add event listener for incoming URLs
    const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);

    // Cleanup the event listener on unmount
    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
  // OAuth Configuration
  const config = {
    issuer: 'https://login.salesforce.com', // For Salesforce login
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxx',           // From your Salesforce connected app
    redirectUrl: 'salesforceDemo://oauth/callback', // Match your app's redirect URI
    scopes: ['api', 'refresh_token', 'offline_access'], // Customize based on your needs
  };

  // Function to handle the OAuth login
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await authorize(config);  // Initiates the OAuth flow
      setAuthState(result);  // Stores the OAuth token in the state
      Alert.alert('Login Success', 'You are now authenticated');
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Login Error', error.message);
      console.error('OAuth Error:', error);
    }
  };

  // Function to refresh the access token (if needed)
  const handleRefresh = async () => {
    if (!authState || !authState.refreshToken) return;
    try {
      const newAuthState = await refresh(config, { refreshToken: authState.refreshToken });
      setAuthState(newAuthState);
      Alert.alert('Token Refreshed', 'Your token is refreshed.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Refresh Token Error:', error);
    }
  };

  // Function to revoke the token (logout)
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    if (!authState) return;
    try {
      await revoke(config, { tokenToRevoke: authState.accessToken });
      setAuthState(null);  // Clears the token from the state
      Alert.alert('Logged Out', 'You are now logged out.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Revoke Error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <Button title="Login with Salesforce" onPress={handleLogin} />
      
      {authState && (
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text>Access Token: {authState.accessToken}</Text>
          <Text>Refresh Token: {authState.refreshToken}</Text>
          <Text>Token Expires In: {authState.accessTokenExpirationDate}</Text>

          <Button title="Refresh Token" onPress={handleRefresh} />
          <Button title="Logout" onPress={handleLogout} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default OAuthComponent;
I have also added intent-filter in my Android Manifest file. android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="salesforceDemo" android:host="oauth/callback" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false" />
  </application>

Right now i am getting a login screen and once i get enter my credentials i am navigated to a salesforce page but not redirected to my mobile app.
I was hoping as i have given redirect Url and added salesforceDemo as intent-filter in my android manifest file it should redirect to my mobile app but that is not happeing.
Currently i am running a virtual device in Android studio for this.
How i can fix this issue?
